# generate geo tiles from vector data

Tags: orm, dictionary, geospatial, geo

i am facing this problem : I have in my database some vector data (polylines ...) which describe many world/country/region/cities boundaries.

I would like to have an interactive map on thoses areas.

When i render those data in the browser (data are sent in geojson) this is slow (i'am not surprised).

The next reason, is to generate some raster tiles to represent the areas at different zoom level and to have a way to make the relation between a click on a area and the area selected (to display more info).

I am a newbie in geo tiles :

- What is the best tool to generate png/jpg tiles from vector data?
- How to make relation between an area clicked and a "id" in database?

I know my questions are very large, but if you have some advices ...

Thanks!

Comment: What's your database? For example, mongo supports 2d [geospatial indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/).

Comment: Also, +1 for using data as a plural. -1 though for asking two questions in one.

Comment: I am using Mongodb, but geoindexing is not really my problem, my problem is to serve quickly an interactive map at different zoom level. And using vector data and render it at client side is too slow ... That's why i am thinking about generate statics/rasters tiles to make it possible. (sorry for the two questions at the same time)

Comment: How are you rendering it?

Comment: Leaflet.js with geojson layer renderer, it's quite slow :(

Comment: something like this : http://bl.ocks.org/glenrobertson/3725681

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a blog posting on how to improve the rendering speed of raster tiles:
  http://blog.webfoot.com/2013/03/12/optimizing-map-tile-generation/

As for connecting a click to a jurisdiction ID, I don't think there is a shortcut: you need to translate the click into lat/lng (or Vast Coordinate System, as I describe in the blog post) and then do a point-in-polygon check.  If you are using PostGIS, then you can do an ST_Intersects.

NOTE: if you are using MySQL, the intersection is done with *bounding boxes*, not the polygons.  It still is possible: you just need to grab a point-in-polygon function from somewhere to check which polygon if a bounding-box check gets you more than one.

Here is an example of dots you can click on:
   http://maps.webfoot.com/demos/CanadianStimulus/CanadianStimulus.html

Note that because people aren't precise with clicking (especially with tiny dots), I actually make a few pixels around the dots "live" as well as the single-pixel dots.  You can also click away from the dot, and then it will show the polygon (which in this example's case, is the federal electoral district).

Comment: Thanx Kailtlin, unfortunately i have moved from mysql with geographic module to mongo because i didn't need spatial calculations (juste accessing geographics data, which mondo does well). But i will use a classic intersection method.

I will read with attention your post. Thx!

Comment: What is your software stack to generate your tiles from you mysql points/polylines etc? I don't know which library to use to generate  png files from spatials data (opengis format/geojson or other)

Comment: I rolled my own.  I draw polygons using the gd library (http://www.boutell.com/gd/) with PHP, but really any graphics library and language would do.

Comment: Uh, I should note that the hard part is loading the data into my database.  I have one table for jurisdictions, one table for polygons, and one table for points.  I had to modify shp2mysql in order to do that.  That means that it is simple to do queries to get all the points for all the polygons in a certain jurisdiction, ordered by polygon => easy to draw the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [MongoDB Plugin datasource](http://repo.opengeo.org/org/geotools/gt-mongodb/) for [Geoserver](http://www.geoserver.org), a full featured WebGIS Server. You can use it to build up a map rendering service (a WMS actually) ofyour data. Then use [Geowebcache](http://www.geowebcache.org) to generate tiles of your map.

This way you can use  fully featured WebGIS stack, which allows you to manage additional datasources, and easy tile subset recreation if portions of your data get updated.

Also querying features on a map (relation map position to element in database) is provided through Geoservers WFS implementation.